# Point cloud not showing up in Qt+PCL viewer

Tags: qt, point-cloud-library, point-clouds, qvtkwidget

I'm trying to load and display point clouds through a Qt+PCL configuration.

I managed to load and display a smaller point cloud (~60 thousand points), but could't display a larger one (~3 million points). Worrying that it might be a limitation on PCL, I've tried displaying both clouds directly through the PCL Visualizer class, without using Qt, and booth clouds were displayed fine.

I assume it's something to do with QVTKWidget. Is the widget somehow limiting point cloud size? From what I understand, QVTKWidget only displays PCL Visualizer's render window, which makes me suspect it's a limitation on VTK's end. Or can it be something else?

My Qt+PCL configuration is based on

- https://pcl-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/qt_visualizer.html#qt-visualizer and
- https://pcl-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/qt_colorize_cloud.html#qt-colorize-cloud.

Displaying through PCL Visualizer class based on https://pcl-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pcl_visualizer.html#pcl-visualizer.

- PCL 1.8
- Qt 5.14.2

Comment: If you're still having this issue, try just displaying a Pointcloud<PointXYZ>. For some reason colored clouds don't work.

Comment: Thank you for the comment Sean. I still have the problem, and I need to display colored point clouds (working on point annotation). What I'm doing is using a separate thread to use PCLVisualizer.

Comment: Does running PCLVisualizer on a separate work to display colored clouds?

Comment: it works perfeclty! only qvtkwidget doesn't work

Comment: Hi @MacrosDiaz, how to make it work? Do you show pcl viewer in a child thread? I'm try to show multiple pcl viewers in child threads, but they are not shown up. I'm not using qvtkwidget.